# How to solve the final test case of HackerRank's Gemstone problem

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have been trying a problem on HackerRank:

- Practice > Algorithms > Strings > [Gemstones](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/gem-stones/problem)

Basically wants me to look for character element that are repeating in every string array element.

### Description

There is a collection of rocks where each rock has various minerals embeded in it. Each type of mineral is designated by a lowercase letter in the range `ascii(a - z)`.

There may be multiple occurrences of a mineral in a rock. A mineral is called a *gemstone* if it occurs **at least once** in each of the rocks in the collection.

Given a list of minerals embedded in each of the rocks, display the number of types of gemstones in the collection.

#### Example

```java
arr = ['abc','abc','bc']
```

The minerals `b` and `c` and appear in each rock, so there are `2` *gemstones*.

### My Code

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

class Result {

    /*
     * Complete the 'gemstones' function below.
     *
     * The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
     * The function accepts STRING_ARRAY arr as parameter.
     */

    public static int gemstones(List<String> arr) {
    // Write your code here
     String str[] = new String[arr.size()];
  
        // ArrayList to Array Conversion
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++) {
            str[j] = arr.get(j);
        }
    int c=0;
    int count[]=new int[26];
     for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
      String x=str[i];
       for(int j=0;j<26;j++){
           char y=(char)(j+97);
           if(x.indexOf(y)!=-1)
           count[j]++;
       }   
      }
      for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
          if(count[i]==str.length)
           c++;
       }
       
       return c;
        }
}

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        int n = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());

        List<String> arr = IntStream.range(0, n).mapToObj(i -> {
            try {
                return bufferedReader.readLine();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        })
            .collect(toList());

        int result = Result.gemstones(arr);

        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
        bufferedWriter.newLine();

        bufferedReader.close();
        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
}
```

This is my code in which I had to design only the `public static int gemstones(List<String> arr)`.

#### My approach was simple

I made an integer array for the 26 letters and checked if any letter was there in all the array elements. If it was I incremented the counter by 1.

#### My Problem

But for some reason, I was not able to pass the [*30th test case*](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/2223/input00.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAR6O7GJNX5DNFO3PV&Expires=1630827098&Signature=947w1lu817SBUBfk8G0vLCRRdVQ%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain).

On using the custom input option, the answer is as it should be: `0`.

Yet, I am unable to pass this.

Comment: So you're saying the expected answer is 0 and your solution produces 0 but you are still failing the test case?

Comment: Instead of checking all characters and add one to a counter I would remove a character if it is missing in a string so I don’t have to continue checking that specific character. And I wouldn’t start with all characters but instead either the first string in the input list or I would find the shortest string in the list and start with that.

Comment: Although your method-code is not well formatted, it compiles and passes the [3 sample test-cases](https://www.hackerrank.com/rest/contests/master/challenges/gem-stones/download_testcases) plus your 30th. [Run it on IDEone](https://ideone.com/4qizBm) ️

Comment: @purple yes and that is why it's much more problematic for me because I have no way of knowing if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks, I will try that approach as well. I used this one because I didn't feel like writing much code.

Answer (score 0):

All we can do to verify your algorithm is:

- inspecting it theoretically
- deconstructing and unit-testing

### What we know

- Mechanics: test each letter of the alphabet against current position in rock
- Decision: You claim to have chosen it, because you didn't feel like writing much code.
- Style: very compact, no spaces, mixed indentation, 1 line-comment only

### Dissecting the code

Below I have added additional comments to express intend as I understood:

```java
String str[] = new String[arr.size()];  // array of rocks 
// ArrayList to Array Conversion
for (int j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++) {
    str[j] = arr.get(j);
}

int c=0;  // counter for gemstones

int count[]=new int[26];  // 26 counts (for each of the 26 letters in alphabet)
for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){  // for each rock, count letters
  String x=str[i];  // rock to test

  for(int j=0;j<26;j++){  // for each letter in alphabet
    char y=(char)(j+97);  // from decimal ASCII code to lower-case char
    if(x.indexOf(y)!=-1)  // if current letter-char found in rock
        count[j]++;  // increment letter-count
  }

}  // test next rock against alphabet (and count)

for(int i=0;i<26;i++){ // test each letter counter if it satisfies (at least once per rock)
  if(count[i]==str.length)
    c++;  // if satisfied (gemstone found) then increment counter
}
       
return c;  // count of gemstones found
```